# How to auto submit a form just on the change of drop down using php

Tags: php, html, forms

How do you auto submit a form  just on the change of drop down using PHP? i.e. the form should be automatically submitted whenever some one selects a value from the select box.

I know it can be done using jQuery and others but I want it to be done only through `PHP`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, it's not possible. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: Why you don't like javascript?

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery, but you would definitely need javascript.

Comment: i can use javascript  but i am not that good in it that is why i was looking for an alternative.......Thanks to all

Comment: I can be done, *technically*, but it's rather crude, just not with an `onchange`. You will need JS for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to use JavaScript for it.

Add an `onchange` or `onblur` event to the html input of your choice with, like this:
`onchange = formName.submit();`

Or, you can do it from a separate JS function, but you have to give an ID to the form. You can do it like this:

- On the input: `onchange = formSubmit();`
- JS:

`function formSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("formID").submit();
}`

The important thing to know about PHP is that it's server side. This means it's the first thing to run, every time you open the page, without exceptions. The serves gets your request for the page, runs the PHP code, then gives the necessary info to your browser which in turn will display the page and runs any JS code.

Comment: i used this         <select name="SelectName" onchange = formName.submit();>    thanks ....

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side scripting, thus you need client side scripting, like js or similar. You can however define an OnChange method:

```
<select name="SelectName" OnChange("href=formhandler.php?SelecteName=this;")>
```

I've used something like this before, but I don't have the actual code at the moment.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: I knew about    onchange() but had no idea where and how to use it....after editing your code it worked    <select name="SelectName" onchange = formName.submit();>     Thanks...

Comment: completely forgot  formName.submit()

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that only with PHP. PHP only runs on the server, not on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PHP is server-side. This means, the code is only executed on the server, an HTML page is sent to the user. You have to use javascript for this (jQuery is javascript), this is executed in the browser and allows you to manipulate the page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done using only PHP. PHP is a server-side language, meaning it has no way of interacting directly with the browser once the page has been loaded. You will need to implement this using JavaScript (you can use jQuery or 'vanilla' JS). In jQuery, this is very easy to do via the [.change() method.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)